# Compute $\iint_D e^{(x+y)^2} \ dxdy.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $$\iint_D e^{(x+y)^2} \ dxdy,$$
>
> where $D=\{ y\leq3x, \ x\leq 3y, \ 0 \leq x+y \leq 2 \}.$

The area $D$ is easily drawn:

[image]

From this image, it's easy to seet that we can split the integral into two parts:

$$\iint_D e^{(x+y)^2} \ dxdy = \int_0^{1/2}\int_{x/3}^{3x}e^{(x+y)^2} \ dydx+\int_{1/2}^{3/2}\int_{x/3}^{2-x}e^{(x+y)^2} \ dydx = \frac{e^4-1}{4}.$$

This is the correct answer. The problem here is that I actually did not compute those two integrals myself, I entered them in Maple and for each one of them I got the answers in terms of the error function, however they canceled out luckily and I was left with the correct answer.

Can anyone help me evaluating this integral by a clever substitution so that I don't have to deal with non-elementary functions?

Comment: Looks like you should use polar coordinates.

Comment: I thought so too. But the exponent would have been nicer if it was $x^2+y^2$. I will try polar for this too then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT...You can use the following change of variables: let $$u=x+y$$ and $$v=\frac yx$$

The Jacobian is $$\frac{u}{(1+v)^2}$$ and the integral works out quite easily to get your answer. I shall leave this to do yourself.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, once I know the proper substitutions, things are straight forward. How did you know that making these substitutions, will work out so well? Experience or is there anything specieal to look for?

Comment: Look for a substitution which makes the limits simple, and see if the resulting Jacobian will make the integrand integrable

Answer (score 2):

Let use polar coordinates

- $x=r \cos \theta$
- $y=r \sin \theta$

with

- $\theta_1=\arctan \frac13$
- $\theta_2=\arctan 3$
- $0\le r \le \frac{2}{\sin \theta + \cos \theta}$ (since $y+x=2 \iff r\sin \theta + r \cos \theta=2$)

thus

$$\iint_D e^{(x+y)^2} \ dxdy =\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}d\theta\int_0^{\frac2{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}}re^{r^2(1+\sin 2\theta)}dr$$

we obtain

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}d\theta\int_0^{\frac1{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}}re^{r^2(1+\sin 2\theta)}dr=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}
\left[\frac{e^{r^2(1+\sin 2\theta)}}{2(1+\sin 2\theta)}\right]_{0}^{\frac2{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}}d\theta=\\\frac{e^4-1}2\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \frac{1}{1+\sin 2\theta} d\theta=\frac{e^4-1}2\left[ \frac{\tan \theta}{1+\tan \theta}\right]_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}=\frac{e^4-1}2\left(\frac34-\frac14\right)=\frac{e^4-1}4$$